# How can I generate multicore load on Stata/MP?

Tags: stata

I'm working on monitoring CPU and memory usage of Stata/MP (the multicore version of Stata/SE) but I am not a Stata programmer (more of a Perl guy).

Can anyone post some code that utilizes a public data set to generate enough load on Stata/MP such that four CPU cores are utilized (or even maxed out) for several minutes or so?

If you can provide me with a .do file and a .dta file (or whatever I may need for this), I think I can take it from there.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question, because it does not deal with statistical analysis, is not really appropriate on the stats site.  You would likely get a fast and authoritative answer from the Stata user's listserve at http://www.stata.com/statalist/ .  In the meantime let's migrate it to the relevant Stack Exchange forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sysuse auto
expand 10000
bootstrap: logistic foreign price-gear_ratio
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Clear memory before each run
// http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?clear
clear all

// Allocate plenty of memory
// http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?memory
set memory 1024m

// Load data set: 1978 Automobile Data
// (Use "sysuse dir" to list other data sets)
// http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?sysuse
sysuse auto

// Duplicate observations
// http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?expand
expand 10000

// Bootstrap sampling and estimation
// http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?bootstrap
// Generate high load using example from bootstrap documentation
bootstrap: regress mpg weight gear foreign
// Generate even higher load and for a longer period
//bootstrap: logistic foreign price-gear_ratio
```

This answer is based on an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183248/how-can-i-generate-multicore-load-on-stata-mp/5183357#5183357), but I added some comments, some setup, and an extra bootstrap command that generates less load.  You can put this into a file called "load.do" and execute it in Stata with File -> Do.  Click the Break button to stop execution.

Please feel free to merge this into the earlier answer if that is more appropriate.